# Autorefresh dotnet run C#/NET - doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I just started watching tutorials on C#, so don't judge too harshly for a poorly worded question.
Essence:
I created a template: dotnet new mvc -au none --no-https
Launched the terminal with command: dotnet run
Then I made changes to the file - Views-Home: Index.cshtml

After that, the information on the web page is not updated for me. I have to stop the server by pressing Ctrl + C, then enter: dotnet run (again).
After that, all the changes made are displayed.
However, for the author, changes to the site occur automatically, that is, he does not constantly restart the server.

Comment: Are you looking for the [dotnet watch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/dotnet-watch?view=aspnetcore-6.0) command?

Comment: @gunr2171 I used **dotnet watch run** and the project was rebuilt with every change in the code.
I tested on my project, it's strange, but the examples from the Microsoft website did not work for me. Now I will not understand why, I will continue my studies, maybe someday I will come to an answer.